# jquery datepicker event search questions

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the jquery event search datepicker in my code which is present [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-search)
. I am new to jquery and I am using the exact same code. The default date is set to one week ahead of the current date.

1. how do i make the default date to the current day? (simple question, but what is the correct format to do so?).
2. since i am using 2 fields from and to, i then want the default date to be changed according to the value selected in from field. suppose i select 20th june 2009, i want the TO field to show up from 21st June 2009 and not the current date. Can this be even done (too good that jquery automatically disables all the dates that fall before the FROM field).
3. i tried to change the dateformat with this code, `dateformat: "yy-mm-dd",`  but it does not change.. shows the default way of mm/dd/yyyy.
4. can i disable the from and two fields, i do not want anyone trying to manually change those values.

**Code:**

```
$(function() {
    var dates = $( "#from,#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "null",dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,disabled:true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" );
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            if(this.id=="from"){
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" );
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            var date2 = $('#from').datepicker('getDate', '+1d');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1); 
            dates.not( this ).datepicker("option", option, date2);
        }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `defaultDate: "+1w"`, see explanation for the option defaultDate one the page you've indicated.
2. Change the code in `onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {` to choose the date for the second selector to be "the next day".
3. `dateFormat`, not `dateformat`
4. When you want to disable them, use `$("#from,#to").datepicker("disable")`

More generally the documentation in jquery UI is really good : try to look at all option/methods available and find the one that will do what you are looking for.

Comment: I have changed defaultDate and dateFormat but could not figure out the 2 and 4th point of changing date and to disable the from and to fields. I have presented my code here.

Comment: For point 2, can you give an example of what "selectedDate" looks like ? (Use `alert(selectedDate)`).

Comment: It is showing up whatever i am selecting.. for ex: 2010-08-10 for from and all the values before 10th august are disabled and for to field when calender opens it is showing from the default date(current date) and not the month of august. for the to field i want it to be shown based on the selection made in the from field. I dont want the user to go back to the same from field date if he is date range is just 1 day. i hope i am clear. and how can i disable the 2 fields?

Comment: To disable, I've updated my answer. So you've got "2010-08-10", instead of using `selectedDate` to build `date` that will be given to `datepicker( "option", option, date )` you should use "selectedDate+1". Look at what `date` looks like, is it a Date object, a string ? Then figure a way to add one day to it.